# Select same column for 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 basic tables :

```
Table1
id1 | lastModif_date
1     10/10/10 
2     10/10/10
3     10/10/10
```

and

```
Table2
id2 | lastModif_date
1     11/02/11 
2     11/02/11
```

I'd like to have a select query that return

```
id1  | id2  | lastModif_date
1      null   10/10/10
2      null   10/10/10
3      null   10/10/10
null   1      11/02/11
null   2      11/02/11
```

This must be really easy to do, but I can't catch it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select table1.id1, null as id2, table1.lastModif_date from table1
union all
select null, table2.id2, table2.lastModif_date from table2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID1, NULL AS ID2, lastModif_Date
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT NULL AS ID1, ID2, lastModif_Date
FROM Table2
```

Comment: Enjoy your `UNION` performance penalty. `id1` and `id2` are almost certainly unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id1, NULL AS id2, lastModif_date FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL as id1, id2, lastModif_date FROM Table2
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to have join query and make alias of the table and then u can access...

```
select id1, id2, lastModif_date
from
(
select * from table1

union all

select * from table2
)
```

Comment: This is so wrong. Let's not even begin with the "join query" followed by an example that has no joins...

Comment: ok yeah, i hav written join query thats wrong...... but the query is working perfectly.....

Comment: Table1 and Table2 have two columns. Unioning them yields a result set with... two columns. Your query selects from 3 columns. It will not run.

Comment: When the names of the columns are different then it will result into separate columns and thats why the result will be 3 columns (id1, id2, lastModif_date). this is because union all will have all the columns of all the tables and if names are same then only it will considered as same else different...

Comment: `id1, lastModif_date` unioned with `id2, lastModif_date` results in `id1, lastModif_date`. I suggest you *actually try this* in MySQL before commenting further.